# Initializing a Polymer property of type Object

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

```
Polymer({
            is: "sustenagro-matrix",
            properties: {
                numbers: Number,
                params: {},
                space: String
            },
            ready: function() {
                Matrix(this.space, this.params);
            }
        });

<sustenagro-matrix numbers="1" params="{ 
                    x: 10,
                    y: 10,
                    label_x: 'Indice da sustentabilidade',
                    label_x: 'Indice de eficiência',
                    range_x: [0,150],
                    range_y: [0,150],
                    quadrants: [5,5]
                    }" space="#matrix1">
            </sustenagro-matrix>
```

It is not working this:

```
                 params="{ 
                    x: 10,
                    y: 10,
                    label_x: 'Indice da sustentabilidade',
                    label_x: 'Indice de eficiência',
                    range_x: [0,150],
                    range_y: [0,150],
                    quadrants: [5,5]
                 }"
```

params is getting passed but not as an object. Does anyone know why and how I fix it?

here comes a piece of the js file to give you all a better idea

```
var width = params['width'] || 640;
var height= params['height'] || 480;
var x= params['x'] || 0;
var y= params['y'] || 0;
var label_x= params['label_x'] || 'label X';
var label_y= params['label_y'] || 'label Y';
var rx= params['range_x'] || [-4, 4];
var ry= params['range_y'] || [-1, 1];
var qds= params['quadrants'] || [4, 3];
var recomendations= params['recomendations'] || [];
```

it's been passing as string and the js file gets all the default values instead of the vaues I passed...

Answer (score 2):

You have to use correct JSON notation when passing in your params object.

```
params='{ "x": 10,
```

Make sure that you use single quotes in the outer string `params='...'` and double quotes for all the keys and strings in your object (`"key": value`).

Also, you should set the type of the property to `Object` instead of `{}`.

```
        properties: {
            numbers: Number,
            params: Object,
```

Comment: I don't know if I did it correctly, but didn't work either... =/ it's been passing as string...

Comment: I also noticed that the property's type is not set properly. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
<sustenagro-matrix numbers="1" params='{ 
                "x": 10,
                "y": 10,
                "label_x": "Indice da sustentabilidade",
                "label_x": "Indice de eficiência",
                "range_x": [0,150],
                "range_y": [0,150],
                "quadrants": [5,5]
                }' space="#matrix1">
```

Comment: The JSON format here should do the trick in combination with the right property declaration from my answer. I don't see any other issues.